# background: url(~assets) doesnt work in ionic app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have in scss

```
 background: url('~assets/icons/refresh-btn.svg') no-repeat center transparent;
```

and bug in console

```
Can't resolve 'assets/icons/refresh-btn.svg' in 'C:\pet\applications\streetkid-app\src\app\modules\layout\components\header'
```

How can this ionic application explain where the assets are?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically related to how the bundler is configured.

Try `url(src/assets/icon/refresh-btn.svg)` or `url(assets/icon/refresh-btn.svg)`

Comment: it doesnt work!

Comment: Could you set up a public repository?